# Best practice for making an ajax call using React and react-router

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-router

My React component requires an ajax call to get the data to render itself.

Initially, I used the approach to make an ajax call kicked off within render.  Here is my pseudo code...

```
export class MyView extends React.Component<any, any> {

    hasAjaxData: boolean = false;

    renderAndGetData() {
        const data = {

        };

        AjaxCall(data)
            .then((results) => {
                this.hasAjaxData = true;
                // save to store here, causing a rerender
                ...
                });
            })
            .catch((err: Error) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
        return (
            <SpinnerComponent />
        );
    }

    renderWithData() {
        return (
            <div>
                Render with data here
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return this.hasAjaxData ? this.renderWithData() : this.renderAndGetData();
    }
}
```

After reading in the React documentation about the [render call](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render), I was a bit concerned about changing the store in a render call, even asynchronously.

I came up with another approach that uses componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.  This ended up being slightly more complicated, since when the component is initially rendered, componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate both get called.  Any subsequent updates (via the URL being changed, then rerendering via react-router) do *not* call componentDidMount, but rather only componentDidUpdate, (which also gets called during the initial mount).  To avoid any unnecessary renders, careful attention to flags is required.

This second approach seems more complicated and involves more function overrides...

So the question is: is there anything wrong with firing off an ajax request from within the render function?

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The `render` function should be [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). This means that making an AJAX call in `render` is strictly verboten. The reason for this is that if your render function can change the state, it can also cause rerenders, and that might cause you to get stuck in a render loop which will be hell to debug.

But even if you write your `render` function carefully, so that you're sure you can never get stuck in a render loop, there are further reasons to keep `render` pure: React expects `render` to be pure, so it is not expecting state changes while it is handling rendering. Although you would need to check React's internals to be sure, I'm pretty sure changing state while rendering will have a serious impact on rendering performance, as it would require React to abort rendering and restart if state changes while rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm only confused because nothing in render itself changes the state.  It's not until the ajax call completes that the state is updated, which is long after the render function has completed cleanly.

With the flag I've set up, render is only called twice.  Once for the loading view, and again after the data is returned.  No looping happens.

Comment: Even asynchronously, you shouldn't be initiating any side-effects in `render`, because that is what the React runtime expects you to do and you should assume the runtime is optimized for that use case. Even if it works now, it might break in some future version of React.